# Control Impress presentation window from openoffice API

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I'm currently attempting to use the openoffice API to display a powerpoint presentation from Java - I've got a fair way in that I've managed to open a presentation and display it. However, there's a couple of things that I'd like to be able to do I can't figure out with the API as it stands:

- I don't want the main Impress window to appear, just the presentation window. Now, I can start it minimized no problem with a property, but then the actual presentation window is minimised as well, which I don't want. I can also grab the window and call `setVisible(false)`  on it, but it's still visible for a second or so while it's loading.
- I want to be able to control the monitor which the presentation appears on (I'm using it in a multi-monitor setup.) I thought I might be able to grab the Window of the presentation and move it around that way as I need to, but I can't see how - for the main window I can do something like:

  `XModel xModel = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XModel.class, xDrawDoc);`
  `xModel.getCurrentController().getFrame().getContainerWindow().blah();`

  ...but I haven't yet found a way to get the presentation Window. I'd like to be able to set the bounds of the window directly (x, y, width, height) rather than just being constrained by positioning on a single monitor.

I can live with the first point, the critical one I need to solve for my use case is the second.

Any ideas on the above? I'm an experienced Java programmer but new to UNO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the second point can be solved, ish, with the display property:

```
public void start() { 
    try { 
        xPresentation.setPropertyValue("Display", 1); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    xPresentation.start(); 
}
```

Note however a few of things - firstly the display index is base 1, not 0. Secondly, trying to set the properties in an array and passing them to xPresentation on creation didn't seem to have any effect - it only worked for me setting the property later as above. Thirdly, it doesn't allow fine grained control over the window as I wanted, just control of the display the presentation appears on.